# Update File in Bitbucket Repo from Another Repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a config repository that holds configuration of the build Pipeline in Bitbucket and i have ~10 other bitbucket repositories that I want to use the configuration file from the config repository after each commit to Master branch. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

That kind of request is followed by the ticket [`BCLOUD-14078`](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-14078) since 2017

> I have been able to share nearly everything needed for builds using a single project that is included as a git submodule.
> The `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file is the only file that cannot be reused.

So far, this is not supported.